# How do I create a new instance of my cart_item in my products controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I am creating a simple store.

My schema is:

```
cart_items(product_id, cart_id, quantity)

carts()

products(title, price, inventory)
```

Now, what I am trying to do is have button on the products page to create a cart. Then in the show page for each product have an `add_to_cart` button that creates a `cart_item` with the `product_id` and the `cart_id` from the most recent cart.

I know how to do this on the console.

```
CartItem.create(cart: Cart.last product: 'some product', quantity: 1)
```

Because the only parameter that will change is the `product_id`. I figure I need to create a method in `ProductsController` called `add_to_cart` which takes the current `product_id` and creates the line item.

I am new to ruby on rails and I do not know how to do this properly and if what I am trying is the right way.

How do I have a button on my products show page that says `add_to_cart` and creates the `cart_item` with that `product_id` and the last cart?

**Update:**

path for `add_to_cart` is `add_to_cart`. When I make it `Add_to_cart_path` there is an error asking `did you mean 'Add_to_cart_path_url'` which leads to another error if I change it.

The error I am currently getting is `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`

My method is

```
def add_to_cart
  product_id = params[:product_id]
  CartItem.create(product: Product.find(product_id), cart: Cart.last, quantity: 1)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting product from product show page just add a `product_id` with `link_to`

```
link_to 'Add to cart', your_add_to_cart_controller_path(product_id: @product.id)
```

And get this `product_id` in your `add_to_cart` method.

**Update**

```
def add_to_cart
  product = Product.find_by(id: params[:product_id]) if params[:product_id].present?
  CartItem.create(product: product, cart: Cart.last, quantity: 1) if product.present?
end
```

Comment: I think this is on the right track. It is working better however, it now gives the error that add_to_cart was expecting no arguments but it got one

Comment: Can you add routes for `add_to_card` method and please add error in question

Comment: Also add params you got when you click `add_to_cart` button from terminal

Comment: Updated the post. I am not sure what you mean in your last comment though. Are you asking for the error that is displayed in the terminal when I am on my app and click 'add to cart' ?

Comment: Please check my updated answer and I am asking about routes for your method and logs when you click on link. Please share output of this command . `rake routes | grep add_to_cart`